# Magento 2.1.9 Javascript files throw errors after migration

Tags: javascript, magento2

I have got this weird problem after taking a copy of a live website and moving it on the dev server. Looks like javascript files are giving me errors.

Also comparing the js code from live to dev there is differences on some parts.

Example of javascript errors im getting in home page:

This is somewhere inline

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdownDialog is not a function
>       at (index):606
>       at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>       at Module.check (require.js:866)
>       at Module. (require.js:1113)
>       at require.js:132
>       at require.js:1156
>       at each (require.js:57)
>       at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
>       at Module.check (require.js:917)
>       at Module.enable (require.js:1143)

on dropdown.js this.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

On i18n.js this

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

For example I took the end of 2 files in this case the i18nJS file and compared them. Live one got more code in the end than the one of the developement server and also it misses the `setText(el, $.mage.__(original));`

i18nJS file from live.

```
execute = function(element, valueAccessor, isUpdate) {
    var original = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor() || '')
      , el = getRealElement(element, isUpdate)
      , inlineTranslation = (module.config() || {}).inlineTranslation;
    if (inlineTranslation) {
        setTranslateProp(el, original);
    } else {
        setText(el, $.mage.__(original));
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.i18n = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        execute(element, valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        execute(element, valueAccessor, true);
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.i18n = true;
renderer.addNode('translate', {
    binding: 'i18n'
}).addAttribute('translate', {
    binding: 'i18n'
});
});
```

i18nJS from dev

```
execute = function (element, valueAccessor, isUpdate) {
        var original = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor() || ''),
            el = getRealElement(element, isUpdate),
            inlineTranslation = (module.config() || {}).inlineTranslation;

        if (inlineTranslation) {
            setTranslateProp(el, original);
        } else {
            setText(el, "'"
    .addAttribute('translate', {
        binding: 'i18n'
    });
});
```

Thats just one file. But all of them are missing something like `$.mage()___('Close');` or something.

Also There are strings not showing up correctly in the backend.

Examples:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

So what I tried:
I tried developer mode
I tried production mode

```
rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preproccesed
```

Redeploying the whole static files.

The only difference that the 2 servers have is one is running cpanel, and the other one is running plesk both on php 7.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the js errors you are getting.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mp1ukx ive edited the post aswell. This is from the home page

Comment: Please add them to the description.

Comment: I've added them